# Convert ISO8601 date with timezone to DateTime in Julia

Tags: string, datetime, julia

Having ISO8601 datetime strings like `2020-11-22T12:14:50+0100` and `2020-11-22T12:14:50+0200` (note the different timezone), is it possible to use Julia's `Dates.DateTime(::DateTime, ::DateFormat)` to convert this to a proper datetime by adding some wildcard characters in the `DateFormat`? We learn from [the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates):

> DateTime type is not aware of time zones (naive, in Python parlance), analogous to a LocalDateTime in Java 8. Additional time zone functionality can be added through the TimeZones.jl package, which compiles the IANA time zone database

```
x = ["2020-11-22T12:14:50+0100", "2020-11-22T12:14:50+0200"]
Dates.DateTime.(x) # fails
    
# somewhat hacky but doesn't fail.
x = replace.(x, r"\+0.+00" => "") 
Dates.DateTime.(x, DateFormat("y-m-dTH:M:S"))
# 2-element Array{DateTime,1}:
#  2020-11-22T12:14:50
#  2020-11-22T12:14:50
```

Would be there any way to add wildcards to avoid `replace`?
E.g.

```
# not run
Dates.DateTime.(x, DateFormat("y-m-dTH:M:S+0*00"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs you quoted suggest, this functionality is provided by the [TimeZones.jl](https://juliatime.github.io/TimeZones.jl/stable/) package. That's the best way to do this:

```
julia> using Dates, TimeZones

julia> x = ["2020-11-22T12:14:50+0100", "2020-11-22T12:14:50+0200"]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "2020-11-22T12:14:50+0100"
 "2020-11-22T12:14:50+0200"

julia> ZonedDateTime.(x, DateFormat("y-m-dTHH:MM:SSzzzz"))
2-element Array{ZonedDateTime,1}:
 2020-11-22T12:14:50+01:00
 2020-11-22T12:14:50+02:00

julia> DateTime.(x, DateFormat("y-m-dTHH:MM:SSzzzz")) # Drops the timezone
2-element Array{DateTime,1}:
 2020-11-22T12:14:50
 2020-11-22T12:14:50
```

If you really just want to trash all TimeZone information, I'd probably do it by `split`ting on the final `+` or `-` character instead of using a regex (there are some [half- and even quarter-hour timezones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html), so your regex won't always work).

```
julia> first.(rsplit.(x, [['+','-']], limit=2))
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "2020-11-22T12:14:50"
 "2020-11-22T12:14:50"

julia> DateTime.(first.(rsplit.(x, [['+','-']], limit=2)), DateFormat("y-m-dTH:M:S"))
2-element Array{DateTime,1}:
 2020-11-22T12:14:50
 2020-11-22T12:14:50
```